# Linux package to display a given text bigger

Tags: linux, banner

Is there a Linux package that can output any text passed to it in a bigger size, essentially without changing font size of the terminal. Basically looking for something like this;

```
$ echobig "hi there!"
 _     _   _   _                   _ 
| |   (_) | | | |                 | |
| |__  _  | |_| |__   ___ _ __ ___| |
| '_ \| | | __| '_ \ / _ \ '__/ _ \ |
| | | | | | |_| | | |  __/ | |  __/_|
|_| |_|_|  \__|_| |_|\___|_|  \___(_)
```

Probably accepting arguments like horizontal and vertical widths for characters to be around.

Edit: I'm looking for a program that accepts text, and prints them. Not 'image-to-ascii' converters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use figlet for making large letters out of ordinary text

http://www.figlet.org/

Answer (score 2):

The `figlet` mentioned by @Chamara Keragala can match exactly the output of your example.

But the classic name for such a tool is `banner`:

```
$ banner "hi there!"
                                                                  ###
 #    #     #             #####  #    #  ######  #####   ######   ###
 #    #     #               #    #    #  #       #    #  #        ###
 ######     #               #    ######  #####   #    #  #####     #
 #    #     #               #    #    #  #       #####   #
 #    #     #               #    #    #  #       #   #   #        ###
 #    #     #               #    #    #  ######  #    #  ######   ###
```

There are several implementations around: I think SysV `banner` is horizontal and not very adjustable, while BSD `banner` (in Debian 10 as `printerbanner`) turns the text 90 degrees right to achieve a very large output by default.